# R store each results of iteration under repeat{}

Tags: r, repeat

I am new in R.

I am trying to simulate a SMRA auction process by using R, which depended heavily on repeat{}, the result I expected is that I could store the outputs of each repeat{} stage by either data.frame or matrix form, and also the times of iterations.

So far I have come up with this. I tried to use the package "xlsx" to store the outputs to Excel sheets, but it didn't work as expected.

[this is what I thought I could get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aIL6.png)

[and this is what I actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YFz4.png)

```
install.packages("xlsx", dependencies=TRUE)
library(xlsx) #load the package

set.seed(777)

vA<-c(round(runif(6,min=0,max=100)))
vB<-c(round(runif(6,min=0,max=70)))
vC<-c(round(runif(6,min=0,max=80)))

v<-rbind(vA,vB,vC)
colnames(v )<-c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6")

bA<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
bB<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
bC<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
b<-rbind(bA,bB,bC)
colnames(b)<-c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6")

bdwnr<-c(NA,NA,NA)
wnprz<-c(NA,NA,NA)

LimPrz<-c((round(runif(1,1,100)*0.2,0)),
 (round(runif(1,1,70)*0.2,0)),
 (round(runif(1,1,80)*0.2,0))
 )

repeat{
 for(i in 1:nrow(b)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(b)){
   if(v[i,j]<LimPrz[i]){
     b[i,j]=0
   }else if(v[i,j]==LimPrz[i]){
    b[i,j]=v[i,j]
   }else if((floor(0.1*v[i,j]+LimPrz[i]))<v[i,j]){
    b[i,j]=(floor(0.1*v[i,j]+LimPrz[i]))
   }else{
    b[i,j]=v[i,j]
   }
  }
 }

 k<-max.col(b)
 for(i in 1:nrow(b)){
  wnprz[i]=(max(b[i,]))
   if(k[i]==1){
   bdwnr[i]="p1"
  }else if(k[i]==2){
   bdwnr[i]="p2"
  }else if(k[i]==3){
   bdwnr[i]="p3"
  }else if(k[i]==4){
   bdwnr[i]="p4"
  }else if(k[i]==5){
   bdwnr[i]="p5"
  }else{
   bdwnr[i]="p6"
  }
 }
 Round<-data.frame(LimPrz,b,bdwnr,wnprz)
      print(Round)
write.xlsx(Round,                 file="Round.xlsx",sheetName="RoundResults",row.names=TRUE,col.names=TRUE)
 for(i in 1:nrow(b)){
   if(max(b[i,])>=LimPrz[i]){
   LimPrz[i]=max(b[i,])+1
  }else{
   LimPrz[i]=LimPrz[i]
  }
 }
 if(sum(b)==0)break
}
```

Help is fullheartly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact requirements are, but try a pattern like this. You can replace the outer loop with `lapply` and return what you were writing to the sheet. The result will be a list of tables, which you can then stack.

```
results <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  # computations
  y <- data.frame(a = i, b = i + 1)
  # etc.
  y
})

do.call("rbind", results)
#     a  b
# 1   1  2
# 2   2  3
# 3   3  4
# 4   4  5
# 5   5  6
# 6   6  7
# 7   7  8
# 8   8  9
# 9   9 10
# 10 10 11
```